# Three.js: Animating a Box-like Geometry

Tags: javascript, animation, 3d, three.js

I have built this [snake game](http://mhluska.com/projects/snake/) where the snakes are animated around using a bunch of cube meshes and `THREE.BoxGeometry`:

[image: snake game]

I would prefer each snake to consist of just one mesh and one geometry so that I can easily add textures, rounded edges etc.

I'm trying to take a set of 3d points and convert them into a single geometry that resembles the box-like snakes in the demo (like several `THREE.BoxGeometry` attached together).

I've tried to achieve that using `THREE.CurvePath` and `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry`:

```
_makeSnakeGeometry(positions) {
  const vectors = positions.map(p => new THREE.Vector3(...p));
  const curvePath = new THREE.CurvePath();
  const first = vectors[1];
  const last = vectors[vectors.length - 1];

  let curveStart = vectors[0];
  let previous = curveStart;
  let previousDirection;

  // Walk through the positions. If there is a change in direction, add 
  // a new curve to the curve path.
  for (let vector of vectors.slice(1)) {
    let direction = previous.clone().sub(vector);

    if (vector.equals(first)) {
      curveStart.sub(direction.clone().divideScalar(2));
    }

    if (vector.equals(last)) {
      previous.sub(previousDirection.clone().divideScalar(2));
    }

    if ((previousDirection && !previousDirection.equals(direction)) || vector.equals(last)) {
      curvePath.add(new THREE.LineCurve3(curveStart, previous));
      curveStart = previous;
    }

    previous = vector;
    previousDirection = direction;
  }

  const p = Const.TILE_SIZE / 2;
  const points = [[-p, -p], [-p, p], [p, p], [p, -p]];
  const shape = new THREE.Shape(points.map(p => new THREE.Vector2(...p)));
  const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, {
    steps: 20,
    extrudePath: curvePath,
    amount: 20
  });

  return geometry;
}
```

Unfortunately, it looks quite ugly and we end up with rounded corners where the path direction changes:

[image: ugly snake game]

If I increase the `steps` option, the resulting mesh looks less ugly but the geometry has a large amount of vertices due to the smooth curved edges. I'm concerned about a large vertex count because I may have to recreate this geometry on every animation frame.

To animate the geometry, I've tried to use `geometry.morphTargets` with little success. The morph happens but it, too, looks quite ugly. Perhaps I need to manually animate the vertices of the geometry?

To summarize, my questions are:

- How can I create a geometry with minimal vertices that resembles several box geometries pieced together?
- What is the correct way to animate a geometry when the underlying vertex count can change?

Comment: I think you need to recompute the triangulation for the chain during each update - unless you need a smooth animation?

Comment: Ideally a smooth animation. I would like to have the same result as in the linked demo but using a single geometry.

Comment: this problem can be simplified _a lot_ by just using un-optimized geometry (i.e. each box has its own geometry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build the snake geometry, I ended up merging geometries:

```
_makeSnakeGeometry(positions) {
  positions = positions.map(p => new THREE.Vector3(...p));
  const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

  for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i += 1) {
    const position = positions[i];
    const mesh = makeVoxelMesh(Const.TILE_SIZE, { position });
    mesh.updateMatrix();
    geometry.merge(mesh.geometry, mesh.matrix);
  }

  return geometry;
}
```

`makeVoxelMesh` returns a single cube mesh for one position of the snake. I join them together using `geometry.merge` and repeat the process on every animation frame. It's not perfect because the geometry ends up having extra vertices and faces that it doesn't need to have for such a simple shape. Maybe there is a way to reduce them after the fact?

To animate the snake, I find the four vertices that comprise the head face. I do it by looking at the vertex positions and face normals:

```
_findHeadFaceVertices() {
  const direction = this._direction.clone().multiplyScalar(1 + (Const.TILE_SIZE / 10));
  const headFacePosition = new THREE.Vector3(...this.head).add(direction);
  const { vertices, faces } = this.mesh.geometry;

  // Sort vertices by distance to a point near the snake head and only keep
  // the first few that are equidistant.
  const closest = vertices
    .map(v => [v.distanceTo(headFacePosition), v])
    .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
    .filter((pair, i, sorted) => pair[0] === sorted[0][0])
    .map(pair => pair[1]);

  const result = [];
  const seen = {};

  // Filter the remaining vertices by keeping only ones which belong to faces
  // that point in the same direction as the snake.
  for (let face of faces) {
    for (let vertex of [vertices[face.a], vertices[face.b], vertices[face.c]]) {
      const key = vertex.toArray().toString();
      if (!seen[key] && closest.includes(vertex) && face.normal.equals(this._direction)) {
        seen[key] = true;
        result.push(vertex);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

For animation to work, I had to set `this.mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;` after each animation frame.

[image: snake game]